# React-Router not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my top level component, I have the following `render` method:

```
return (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={FrontPage} />
            <Route path='article/:slug' component={Article} />
        </Switch>
    </main>
);
```

However, judging by debug-purposed `console.log()` outputs, it seems the `FrontPage` component is loaded when visiting the route `/#/article/whatever`.

I'm new to this version of react-router (4.2.2, specifically) ; what am I doing wrong?

I'm using HashRouter at the top level.

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: Try to load /article/whatever instead of /#//article/whatever

Comment: @IgorStecyura: 4.2.2, according to package.json. I'm using HashRouter, so (AFAIK) the # is necessary.